# Firebase does not track clicks on dynamic links

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have created a dynamic link through the Firebase console. The link works correctly according to its flow.

The issue is that the link analytics does not work. On the day of creation, Firebase counted clicks. But on the day after creation, total amount of clicks is equal to zero (while I know that there were at least 11 clicks).

How to solve this?

Comment: On the day of creation - at least, 11 clicks totally,
next day - zero clicks totally,
third day - 10 clicks totally...

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things that may have happened here:

1) There was recently a change that meant that clicks are no longer reported right away. This is actually to enable the new link analytics API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/analytics

2) Dynamic Links also [reports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/analytics) to Google Analytics for Firebase. These reports default to showing "yesterday" which can be a bit confusing. GA also batches its reporting on the client side to save battery, so even though analytics are recorded, they aren't necessarily reported until later.

Comment: Thank you Ian. I will try to investigate the options you proposed.

I also found out that "Statistics might not include events that have been logged within the last 36 hours"

Comment: Thank you Ian.. Can I expect _all_ clicks to have propagated through to the different Analytics clients (Google Analytics for Firebase, Dynamic Links analytics in Firebase and `firebasedynamiclinks` REST-API) after 36 hours? Is there a more realtime way to get this data?